# Gradle Dependencies not recognized in Intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, ide, dependencies

I'm working on a Spring Boot Application using Gradle as a dependency management system or whatever.

After adding a couple of dependencies to the build script and rebuilding the project, I would expect the build to have added those dependencies to the project. And yet, it does not. Cannot import those libraries. What step am I missing?? I am a node.js developer and am used to just running an `npm install` to import dependencies.

Here are the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.2.2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
}
```

Not that it matters, since they were not added to the project, but here are the eventual import statements:

```
import org.mongodb.MongoClient;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
```

Answer (score 20):

Ok, so there is a right-hand menu bar, viz:

[image]

And the gradle tab has a refresh option:

[image]

That'll do it. Ugh, ide's...